# remap esc key introduced remove behave

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'v remapped `esc` key by double `jj` for insert mode and command line mode.

When I using it in command line mode it removes the word where the cursor is highlighted

```
cnoremap jj <esc>
nnoremap rr :s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/
```

The example above shows that rr key for normal mode is highlight the current words and after user input the word and press the enter key, the highlighted words will be replaced. However, after I entered `rr` in normal mode and want to cancel the replace action by press `jj`, it removes the word under the cursor, why is that? and how can I solve this

Comment: Tangent: maybe use `*` for your `rr` command, e.g. `nnoremap rr *``:s//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected behaviour. See [:h c_ESC](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_Esc)

> In macros or when 'x' present in 'cpoptions', start entered command.

In the vim documentation, when mentioning macros, this also applies to mappings and abbreviations (basically whenever the input has not literally been typed).

So if you want to abort a command in command line mode, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> instead.

Comment: Short! Clean! Correct! Precise! and Thanks